# Adding a dynamic value tag to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xslt

I am trying to find a ways to update xml with dynamic value (eg:22341) using c# in bleow query tag at run time which I get it from a another file.

```
 <TablesQueryManager>
          <Query name ="TBKHFG">
          SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= {dynamic value} THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) FROM TBKHFG
          </Query>
          <Query name ="TBKLPG">
            SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= {dynamic value} THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) FROM TBKLPG
          </Query>
   </TablesQueryManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to just put a placeholder in your xml, in your example above the placeholder is "{dynamic value}", and then use [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) to replace the placeholder with the actual value.